# Button click not working Using ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In local working correctly, but when I am doing registration on liver server then some time registration is redirecting to successfully page and some time not redirecting, and also not getting any error message. The registration form is very big, so, I am not putting all design, code but I have taken code from every block. According to me panel are the problem may be, But another thing I had to observe if the page is not registration, then I reload again same page, then fill all details then its taking submission.

Page Load Code:

```
  BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
BusinessObject bo = new BusinessObject();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("MasterpageID");
    body.Attributes.Add("class", "fifth");

    //to restore password field when page refreshes
    txt_Password.Attributes.Add("value", txt_Password.Text);



}
```

Design Code:

```
Nationality:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Nationality" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_Nationality_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Indian" Value="Indian"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Expatriate" Value="Expatriate"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>


    Title: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Title" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Mr." Value="Mr."></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>

    Name:  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" CssClass="textfield_new1" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Country:    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Country" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                   Total Experience:        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_years" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="Exp"
                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_years_SelectedIndexChanged">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Year</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="1">0</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">3</asp:ListItem>

             </asp:DropDownList>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_months" runat="server" CssClass="Exp"
               Enabled="false">
                   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Month</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="1">0</asp:ListItem>

              </asp:DropDownList>
               </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </td> </tr>

    </table>


        <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="None"
            CaptchaHeight="40" CaptchaLength="5" CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" 
        CaptchaMinTimeout="5" FontColor="111, 109, 85" Width="325px" CaptchaWidth="300"
        CssClass="textarea_captha" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
    Enter Text as you See:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" CssClass="textfield_new1"></asp:TextBox>

        </td></tr>

    </table>

    <table>
    <tr><td>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="imgbtn_Submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="reg" CssClass="submitbtn"

    </td></tr>
    </table>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/spacer.gif" />
                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="ImageButton1" PopupControlID="Pnl_popup1"
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="Pnl_popup1"
                                                    runat="server">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_popup1" runat="server">
                                                //pop design code is here

                                                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your update panels are making the problems in redirection. Please note that, update panel is only used for AJAX request. It will post only selected panel data. So it will not make sense to add Update panel, when you want redirection from one page to another.

Remove unnecessary update panels and try to do it. It will help you.

Comment: Ok. So you can use Postback trigger to enforce your post back and redirection. There are also alternate options of update panel. You can use Jquery Ajax instead of update panel.

Comment: Can give me that postback trigger code to my above code. @azhar

Answer (score 0):

add OnClick Event in your Button

Comment: What happens if i add, add on lick event. @aliasghar

Comment: you can add event click and redirect to another page but you must remove your update panel . because don't allow redirect

Comment: Update panel is necessary some place, is there any different solution, its a big form. @aliasghar

Comment: Already i have following code:    if (Status == "Success")
                        {

  Response.Redirect("registrationthanks.aspx");
                        }

Comment: you can use javascript like this `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "redirect", "location.href = 'registrationthanks.aspx'", True)`

Comment: In local server working fine when we are registering form on liver server some time registering and some time not registering. then why its working on local server, i dont know why i have to use that your javascript file. @Aliasghar